# GraphServiceClient throw an exception when AzureAD is not the default authentication scheme

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET Core application I've multiple authentication scheme.

`GraphServiceClient` throw `IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was ''` exception if `OpenIdConnect` is not default scheme. I need 'cookie' as default scheme.

My configuration:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration, configSectionName: "Authentication:AzureAD");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

My Page:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public int UnreadMessages { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromServices] GraphServiceClient graph)
    {
        UnreadMessages = (await graph.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
                                     .Request()
                                     .Filter("isRead ne true")
                                     .GetAsync()).Count;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I can I configure GraphServiceClient to work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to tell GraphServiceClient what authentication schema to use using `WithAuthenticationScheme` method:

```cs
var messages = await graph.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
    .Request()
    .WithAuthenticationScheme(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Filter("isRead ne true")
    .GetAsync();
```